# excel vba filtering and grouping

Tags: vba, excel, filtering, grouping

I have this sheet in excel which i need to apply an `AutoFilter`.

Let's say that "Contract" starts in column A1 and "Comment" in B1. See Example Below:

```
Contract    Comment
111         A
111         b
111         c
222         d
222         f
222         g
333         d
333         f
333         A
444         b
444         d
444         c
```

I want to filter the contracts to show groups/sets of contracts (example of a group/set  of contracts is 111)  of which any of the contracts in that group/set has a comment A. See below:

Note: I have some other Data which is relevant to my application, but it isn't showed in this example.

```
Contract    Comment
111         A
111         b
111         c
333         d
333         f
333         A
```

And also i want to be able to filter by any comment that does not contains "A". Result should be as follows:

```
Contract    Comment
222         d
222         f
222         g
444         b
444         d
444         c
```

Comment: Have you tried the filter options in excel ?

Comment: Firstly, welcome to StackOverFlow. Just for info, this site is not purposed as a "Please give me the code for this" site. But more of a "Help me find the bug in my code" site. Having said that, I have still answered your question below. what is helpful is to use the Macro Recorder in Excel to try and establish want you want to do and then bring it here so we can see whats the solutions or where we can assist you.

Answer (score 0):

This will AutoFilter Contract Column to Sets of contracts, which any contract in that set has a comment of A.

To filterout values you need to add a <> before the text in the Array, this does not seem to work. I therefore added a Loop at the end to go through the rows manuall and see if the COntract values are in the ContainsA Array, if they are then hide the row.

```
Sub SomeSub()

    Dim MyRange As Range, CommentRng As Range, ContractRng As Range
    Dim ContainA As Variant
    Dim i As Integer, k As Integer, r As Integer

    'Getting the Total Rows of the Sheet
    With ActiveSheet.UsedRange
        LastRow = .Rows(.Rows.Count).Row
    End With

    'Setting the USedRange of the Sheet
    Set MyRange = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.UsedRange

    'Setting the Comment and Contract Ranges
    Set CommentRng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 2), Cells(LastRow, 2))
    Set ContractRng = ActiveWorkbook.ActiveSheet.Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(LastRow, 1))

    'Filtering the Comment Column
    MyRange.AutoFilter Field:=2, Criteria1:="A"

    'Getting the number of visible cells in the Contract Range
    ' -1 to remove the First Row of the Comment headin
    ' -1 to set Array correctly, it Array(1) then the array( SomeValue, SomeOtherValue)
    TotalA = ContractRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Count - 2

    'Setting the Array size
    ReDim ContainA(TotalA)
    'Setting the Array size
    ReDim NotContainA(TotalA)

    i = 0
    'For each visible cell in Column 2 "Comment"
    For Each cell In ContractRng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)

        'If the Value is "Comment"
        If cell.Value = "Contract" Then

            'Do nothing

        Else
            'Set the Cell value into the Array
            ContainA(i) = cell
            'Increment i
            i = i + 1
        End If

    Next cell


    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData


    'Filitering the Column 1 Data, the Criteria1 needs to be a string Array
    'Join(Array1) joins the Array as a String
    'Split then splits the String as a String array
    MyRange.AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:=Split(Join(ContainA)), Operator:=xlFilterValues



    ActiveSheet.ShowAllData

    'If you want to hide the groups which contain "A"
    'There is no "FILTEROUT" function
    'so this must be done manually
    For r = 1 To LastRow

        For k = 0 To TotalA

            If Cells(r, 1) = ContainA(k) Then

                Rows(r).EntireRow.Hidden = True

            End If

        Next k

    Next r

End Sub
```

Comment: I have already found solutions like yours, but that isn't what i'm looking for.  Your code will give only 2 results, but i want to be able filter all the same contracts, just like in example 2.

Comment: @Pero do you want filter the "Contracts" Column?

Comment: Yes, it should filter columns contracts and comments i guess. It should be something like this: if one of contracts 111 has comment "a", show all the contracts 111 and their comments.